# Having trouble regarding output of a printf statement

Tags: c, printf, pointer-arithmetic, post-increment

I am having some trouble understanding the output of the following code snippet.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *str;
    str = "%d\n";
    str++;
    str++;
    printf(str-2, 300);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the code is 300.

I understand that Until the line before the `printf` statement, `str` is pointing to the character-`%`. What I need help with is understanding that why is the `printf` function printing 300.

Comment: No, before the `printf` statement `str` is pointing to the newline.

Comment: Im nor sure what you thing this statement is doing: `printf(str-2, 300);`  however, the first parameter is expected to be the format string.  the second and following parameters are the values to supply to the output format specifiers in the format string.  However, it is considered a security risk to reference some variable for the format string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right before the `printf`, `str` is **not** pointing to the `%` but to the `\n`.

The `++` operator increments the value of `str` to point to the next character in the array.  Since this is done twice, it points to the `\n`.  When you then pass `str-2` to `printf`, it creates a pointer pointing back to the `%`.  So `printf` sees the string `"%d\n"` which causes 300 to be printed as expected.

Answer (score 3):

`2 - 2` is equal to `0`.:)

In fact these two expression statements

```
str++;
str++;
```

that can be rewritten like

```
str = str + 1;
str = str + 1;
```

are equivalent to one statement

```
str = str + 2;
```

Then in the statement with printf

```
printf(str-2, 300);
```

you are using the expression `str-2` that points to the first character of the string literal `"%d\n"` Or the value of the expression `str-2` is equal to the original value of `str`.

(Do you remember that `2 - 2 == 0`?)

So the statement above is equivalent to

```
printf(str, 300);
```

when `str` was initially initialized by the string literal `"%d\n"`